# CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've encountered the following error:

> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix swift

I use UIImagePickerController and, when I do photo or choose photo from library, I get this error. I also try to present my photo using `firstImageView`.

Here is my code:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        firstImageView.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an Xcode bug. Don't worry about it. There is nothing wrong with that piece of code.

It's just a console error. You just need to ignore it. Otherwise, try cleaning and deleting derived data, remove the app from the phone, and re-run it.

Comment: but I tested on device (5s)

Comment: But it's just a console error, right? Then you just need to ignore it. Otherwise, try cleaning and deleting derived data, remove the app from the phone, and re-run it.

Comment: not JUST console, with console error I haven't result, that I hoped

Comment: but thanks! I'll try do all you sayed!